# Get Post data of a view in inside a block

Tags: views, blocks

I am actualy tring to get the posted data from a views filter and display it inside a custom block.

This is what my code looks like for now

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function search_block_header_block_info(){
    $block['search_header'] = array(
        'info' => t('Search Header'),
        'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
    );
    return $block;
}

/**
 * Define what our block is going to look like.
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function search_block_header_block_view($block_key){
    $block = array();

    if($block_key == 'search_header'){ //We only want to define the content of OUR block

        dsm($_POST);
        //This is the title of the block.
        $block['subject'] = t('Search Header');
    }

    return $block;
}
```

But for some reason the $_POST variable is always empty. Someone got a hint for me how to get the posted data?

Comment: what is actual use of this ? are you trying to debug or something ? just curious :)

Comment: Hehe I want to put this block above my search form to display the searched string inside a "Drupal Status Message"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$view = views_get_current_view();
dsm($view->exposed_input);
```

instead $_POST.

Comment: My pleasure :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Views** always user **GET** method to pass the parameter to filter the data. 
So if you are checking the data in custom blocks just try getting it by the use of `$_GET['key']`

Views always user params as **Querystring** so its not the right method to get the data i think.